# I'm unable to delete a record from a file using sed command

Tags: sed

I am not able to delete a record using

> > sed '3d' $filename

The record is deleted temporarliy and again if I open the file the record is their.

I tried this and it worked

> > sed -i -e  '3d' $filename

Can anyone explain what is  that -i and -e and what is their significance.
Source for official documentation of bash script where all  syntax are available.

Comment: `man sed` is one of the BEST documentation which personally I refer for `sed` you could easily find this information over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '3d' $filename
```

This command will just display the modified file after performing the operation.

---

```
sed -i -e '3d' $filename
```

The option of `-i` is for updating the file in place. That's why when you executed the second command it updated the contents of the file, in your case deleted the third line.

For more information, you can run "man sed" in your shell prompt and get all the options which can be used with sed.